# Should I only use specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This has been nagging at my head for quite for quite some time (might be a dup).

When asking a question about a specific package or library, lets say `log4j`, should I tag it with "parent topics" as well, in this case `java`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not official response, but my own opinion is: certainly yes - always specify the language used.

Questions on Stack Overflow should be related to programming and programming means there is some language involved - so it is always a good thing to have that language tagged properly.

Of course there are edge cases where it's obvious what is the language, e.g. pure jQuery question where it's obvious JavaScript is the language but in case of plugins I believe it's always a good idea to tag it with the parent language tag as well.

As a bonus, it would usually pretiffy any posted code. :)

Comment: It prettifies code according to tags? Nice! Got a link to the feature's announcement? jQuery is a good example - I always tag these `javascript` as well as `jquery` and sometimes `jquery-ui` as well ... and I'm never sure whether I'm doing good or not.

Comment: Cheers, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/152859) for official post, under "Syntax highlighting". As for jQuery it's one of the rare cases you actually *don't* have to specify the parent tag (JavaScript) as it's trivial plus as far as I know, both tags are the same for pretiffy. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue when you have a question about a wrapper/binding/reimplementation library, for example, [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt), which is a binding for the C++ library [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) in Python.

For some PyQt questions that are more about the library than Python-specific issues, Qt users might know the best solution.

I tend to think that such a question can be tagged with both PyQt and Qt, but it looks a bit strange. And should it have the Python tag as well?